# Mongoid not in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I have some trouble with mongoid:

```
  test "Test candidate" do
    User.create(:id => 1, :sex => User::Male, :country => 1, :city => 1)
    User.create(:id => 2, :sex => User::Female, :country => 1, :city => 1)
    User.create(:id => 3, :sex => User::Female, :country => 1, :city => 1)

    user = User.not_in(:id => [2]).second
    assert_not_equal(user.id, 2)
  end
```

Test failed. I've tried to use where(:id => {'$nid' => [2]}), but it have same effect.

What is wrong? How to use "not in" condition with mongoid?

PS, "second" is ok, with "first" test passed, because id=1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this query:

```
user = User.not_in(:_id => [2]).second
```

In MongoDB primary key has name `_id`. Mongoid tries to be friendly and partially hides this fact from the developer by aliasing it to `id` in the object model. But when you do queries, it cannot tell if you want primary key `_id` or some completely ordinary field `id`.

Answer (score 16):

```
user = User.where(:id.nin => [2,3,4,5])
```

This is as per mongoid official doc : http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html